# Casting Error: Inserting data into Custom MembershipUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

I'm attempting to fill in data to my `NCCMembershipUser` with the following code:

```
string name = User.Identity.Name;

NCCMembershipUser currentUser = (NCCMembershipUser)NCCMembershipProvider.GetUser(name, true);

currentUser.Salutation = GenderSelect.SelectedValue;
currentUser.FirstName = TextBoxFirstName.Text;
currentUser.LastName = TextBoxLastName.Text;
currentUser.Position = TextBoxPosition.Text;
...

try
{
    NCCMembershipProvider u = (NCCMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
    u.UpdateUser(currentUser);
}
```

I am getting an error *"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.GetUser(string, bool)'"*

If I instead use `Membership.GetUser()` (without the `name` string) to access the current user, it gives me a casting error, and `GetUser()` appears it cannot be overridden.

Edit:

The casting error I get is "[A]NCC.App_Code.NCCMembershipProvider cannot be cast to [B]NCC.App_Code.NCCMembershipProvider."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The casting error I get is "[A]NCC.App_Code.NCCMembershipProvider
>   cannot be cast to [B]NCC.App_Code.NCCMembershipProvider."

For this error, verify that you don't have that class in your `App_Code` folder, if so, move it to another place like a new folder called `Membership`

That will take care of the casting issue as the app is compiling 2 different DLLs into 2 different places in the temporary asp.net folders.

Comment: I made a folder called NCCMembership so there wouldn't be any issues with the Membership namespace in System.Web.Security. But that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you that the `GetUser` method isn't [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so it cannot be invoked without an instance of the `NCCMembershipProvider` class.

You have to grab your provider earlier in your method:

```
string name = User.Identity.Name;
NCCMembershipProvider u = (NCCMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

NCCMembershipUser currentUser = (NCCMembershipUser)u.GetUser(name, true);

currentUser.Salutation = GenderSelect.SelectedValue;
currentUser.FirstName = TextBoxFirstName.Text;
currentUser.LastName = TextBoxLastName.Text;
currentUser.Position = TextBoxPosition.Text;
// ...

try
{
    u.UpdateUser(currentUser);
}
```

Comment: This brings me back to the casting error I mentioned in the question. "[A]NCC.App_Code.NCCMembershipProvider cannot be cast to [B]NCC.App_Code.NCCMembershipProvider"

Comment: I think I'm going to have to bypass the provider and just use a datasource control. No one seems to know how to resolve this. It should be so simple.